# .htaccess file is working but causes constant refreshing/redirects

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, lamp

I have changed my .htaccess based on a tutorial to hide the .php file extension and $_Get from URL but the page keeps on jumping.

I have tried a number of .htaccess changes this is the only one that is even partially working. However, it seems to be causing constant redirects/refreshes.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http

RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) $1.php?name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Looking to change `"profile.php?name=company-name"` to `"profile/company-name"` without the page looking or functioning any differently. Some of the `$_Get` dynamic content is loading but the entire page keeps on skipping and none of the CSS styles are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all of your rules with this:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?name=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure to test this change in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

For your css/js/issues add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Anubhava - the page stop refreshing but none of the styles were loading. Also the other pages which only had their .php file extensions altered stopped working as well.

Comment: You are a Knight in shining armor. Thank you very very much.